# Apply ESLint / Prettier to selected lines only

Tags: format, webstorm, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I'm working with WebStorm and there is only two possibilities to use ESLint :

- Apply ESLint to file
- Apply ESLint to a line

Isn't there a possibility to apply ESLint to a selection of multiple lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to apply ESLint fix to selection in WebStorm, ESLint itself doesn't support range formatting/fixing. But you can [import your code style preferences](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html#ws_js_linters_eslint_import_code_style_from_eslint) from `.eslintrc` and then use the built-in formatter (**Code | Reformat Code**) to format the selection.

Note also that you can set up *Prettier* as your [default formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/prettier.html#ws_prettier_default_formatter) and then use it to format a selection with **Code | Reformat Code**